# Using the onclick function for a button and the button content (words) show up but the button is not clickable. Any advice?

Tags: javascript, html

Just doing some practice and I cannot seem to get this button to function. I have checked multiple sites and seem to be formatting it right. Everything else in my code works properly.

Here is the code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>This is a picoCTF JS Example</title>
        <script>
            function myFunctionSum(){
                var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
                var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value
                car result = number(number1) + Number(number2);
                alert(result);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JavaScript example to add2 numbers</h1>
        Input the first number<br>
        <input type="text" id="number1" ><br>
        Input the second number<br>
        <input type="text" id="number2"
        <button onclick="myFunctionSum()"> Show alert! </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is the button portion that seems to not be working. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: `<input type="text" id="number2"` is missing the `>` at the end.

Comment: Oh geez...thank you. Was so focused on the button just assumed rest of the code was good I feel very sheepish.

Comment: you should close input tag and check function name typo number -> Number

Comment: In case you aren't, you should definitely use an editor with code highlighting and error checking. Like VS Code.

Comment: i think its because you use car instead of  var   and  you convert string to number is wrong

Answer (score 1):

`car result = number(number1) + Number(number2);`
its wrong

try this

```
var result= +number1  +  +number2  ;
```